# Adding an additional module to my app

Tags: android, service, module, apk

## Problem

I have a free app in alpha stage at the moment, there is some extra content and functionality that I can imagine my users will want access to.

However as its my first app I do not know the mechanism for including the extra functionality. I see the in-app apk option in the google console but I do not know how I will need to package up my module for it.

My core app will need to pass parameters and call the extra functions in the module, which will display new activities extending my core app. This will only happen if the module is installed.

How do I go about this? Do I just make another app and install it side by side? This would be ok but the other app (my module) really is an extension of my core app and would not make sense on its own.

What is the right method to go about this?

## clarification

I wish to have an optional module, which is not part of the core app but can be added by users on demand.

Ideally this module can also function by itself even though it would not make too much sense. Like a dictionary say of medical terms, it could be used by itself but would make more sense when an addon to a medical app.

It is so large in size and applicable to other potential apps that I cannot permanently include it with my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the `Extra Module` with your current Application's code.
After doing so, change the `VersionCode / versionNumber` in your `Manifest.xml` file of your project.
Then simply export the fresh `.apk` with your existing `Keystore` and upload it to the `PlayStore` over your existing Alpha apk.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my goals, please see my clarification above.